# Generating rows from string arrays

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

this is my first question and I'm pretty new to pyspark. I would like to generate additional rows in my dataset and a string column from two string arrays with the same size. The elements in the two arrays have a 1:1 relation.

Example

Transform this:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+--------+                      
|fruits                    |colors              |taste   |
+--------------------------+--------------------+--------+
|[banana, strawberry]      |[yellow, red]       |good    |
|[blueberry]               |[blue]              |better  |
|[melon, pineapple, cherry]|[green, orange, red]|the best|
+--------------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

into this:

```
+------------------+--------+                                                   
|Connected         |taste   |
+------------------+--------+
|banana - yellow   |good    |
|strawberry - red  |good    |
|blueberry - blue  |better  |
|melon - green     |the best|
|pineapple - orange|the best|
|cherry - red      |the best|
+------------------+--------+
```

Can you give me some support?

Thx,
Markus

Comment: Interesting problem. Have you tried anything, or are you expecting someone to write the answer code for you?

Comment: @C.Nivs: Yes, I tried some variants with the explode function but didn't geht the 1:1 relation to work. I always ended up with both columns exploded independent from each other.

Comment: Add your attempt to the question, I bet you're closer than you think. It also makes it easier for us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (["banana", "strawberry"], ["yellow", "red"], 'good'),
    (["blueberry"], ["blue"], 'better'),
    (["melon", "pineapple", "cherry"], ['green', "orange", "red"], 'the best')
], ['fruits', 'colors', 'taste'])

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('Connected', f.explode(f.expr('transform(fruits, (x, i) -> concat_ws(" - ", x, colors[i]))')))
    .select('Connected', 'taste')
)
    
df.show(truncate=False)
```